# Why is Muon on KDE failing with multiple package errors?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, package-management, muon-package-manager

The following Error message appeared to me and preventing me to updating my SYSTEM.

**The package system could not be initialized, your configuration may be
  broken**

The following error also appeared under details tab:

Encountered a section with no Package: header

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

All I successfully solved this error.

To solve this problem login as root user and type the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, apply new updates, enter:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

type `y` when the terminal asks you `Do you want to continue [Y/n]?`.